# Converting from Access to SQL Back End (Multi-Value Fields)

Tags: ms-access

So I'm converting an access back-end to SQL. I've tried a few different tools (SSMA, Upsizing Wizard, and a simple import). I've found so far that the SSMA tool and importing seem to work the best, eliminating most of the work necessary for me. However, I'm running into one issue I can't figure out how to overcome.

Two fields allow multiple values (dropdown with check boxes). In converting these, it errors in a way that it not only doesn't carry all of the information over, but also grabs information from another field (and doesn't carry that information over).

I've tried forcing access to only accept the first value (and get rid of multi-values all together), but it won't let me.

Any ideas?

Comment: multivalue fields are for compatibility with Sharepoint. You'll probably have to convert them to a 1 to many table structure.

Comment: Hello Brad,

Thank you for your response. What would you say is the best way to convert them?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff821054%28v=office.15%29.aspx

Comment: Brad, I appreciate your help. Unfortunately however, I'm not getting anywhere.

Skipping the migration portion and just coming up with a "going forward" solution, my understanding is that I should be using a join table and may need to do some coding to recognize the multiple selections. Do you have any examples I may look at in practice?

Comment: I'll give you an example when I get off. Kind of swamped atm

Comment: I understand. Thank you Brad. I look forward to seeing it!

Comment: I'm starting to wonder if this is impossible.

I've figured out how to create a subform and display them in a table-like method, but not in the combobox on the existing form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should get you started. It will turn all those values which are selected in the multi select field into their own table. You will need to establish the relationships between the three tables to create a true many to many relationship after the fact.

```
Sub ExtractMultiValueFields()

    Dim JoinTable As New DAO.TableDef
    JoinTable.Name = "JoinTable"
    With JoinTable

        .Fields.Append .CreateField("MainTableId", dbInteger)
        .Fields.Append .CreateField("JoinToValue", dbText)
    End With

    Dim joinRs As DAO.Recordset

     CurrentDb.TableDefs.Append JoinTable

    Set joinRs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("JoinTable")

    Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
    Dim childrs As DAO.Recordset
    Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("select * from table1")
    Do While Not rs.EOF
        Debug.Print rs("ID")
        Set childrs = rs("col1").Value
        Do While Not childrs.EOF
            Debug.Print childrs("value")    'always "value"
            joinRs.AddNew
                joinRs("MainTableId") = rs("ID")
                joinRs("JoinToValue") = childrs("value")
            joinRs.Update
            childrs.MoveNext
        Loop
        rs.MoveNext
    Loop

End Sub
```